# Download paused in play store and doesn't resume

Tags: google-play-store

I am a Gionee M5 user. Recently I have encountered a problem with my play store. Whenever I start downloading any apps, the download pauses automatically and doesn't resume. So I am unable to download or update any apps. I have already tried factory resetting my android. I have also cleared the data and uninstalled updates of play store and download manager. I couldn't figure out it is the problem of playstore or the download manager. None of these above techniques worked. So, I am hoping for someone's help.

Comment: How do you use your network access in your mobile? Have you tried with both the mobile network and wifi? Slow connections might also cause this problem

Comment: Same question asked before (unfortunately, no answers yet): [Paused Download on Play Store](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/141881/16575) / [Google play store not working](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/140649/16575)

Comment: @Izzy We could use someone with this issue that could reflash their own firmware. Since a factory reset didn't help, I'm wondering if the issue is an odd configuration somewhere in the /system partition.

Comment: @Izzy By the way, by looking at the questions you linked back, I can see that the issue seems to affect only "Gionee" devices. Perhaps those devices run a factory customized version of Android, and, if that's the case, I guess that the culprit is indeed the download manager.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman Good catch with the device! If it's something in the `/system` partition, I wonder if a flash (of the same firmware) would accomplish anything. Apart from that, I agree with your reasoning: if the issue survives a factory-reset, a (different) firmware might be necessary (unless one can attack the underlying issue with root powers).

Comment: @Izzy I'll now formulate a completely absurd theory, so correct me if I'm wrong. The thing is that, in my experimenting, I once force closed the download manager (CM12.1). The result was that the Play Store went in an infinite loop: it downloaded the app, didn't acknowledge the fact and started downloading it again. In my case, a simple reboot proved to be enough, but in OP's case, I'm wondering that the download manager doesn't recognize that the device is connected to the internet, and this causes the download to freeze.

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman that's a different issue, rather similar to those we had here where OP disabled the DownloadManager app. It might be related, though, if the DownloadManager doesn't "start up correctly" due to some misconfiguration.

Comment: Thanks all of u for the comments....so what would you all suggest me to do now??

Answer (score 1):

I too had the same issue and I have gone through several forums for the help.All have suggested the same.

> Clear cache and clear data of the playstore.
>   Force stop the playstore.
>   Remove and add google account.

I have tried all of the above but not found any good.

But after a lot of trial and error, i have resolved the issue.

Solution is the same as above but the sequence order is very important.

Please follow the exact order given below.

1). **Google Playstore** - Go to Settings >> Apps>> 'All' tab >> Select Google Playstore - Now Uninstall all updates >>Force stop >> Clear Cache>> Clear Data.

2). **Download Manager** - Go to Settings >> Apps>> 'All' tab >> Select Download Manager - Force stop >> Clear Cache>> Clear Data.

3). **Downloads** - Go to Settings >> Apps>> 'All' tab >> Select Downloads - Force stop if the button is active.

4). Remove the google account.

5). Restart the device.

6). Add Google account.

(Assuming you have followed the sequence properly)

In case the above steps don't resolve the issue and you are using Mobile data then follow the below steps

1 > Check your storage space in your phone and ensure required space is available.

2 > Please go to Settings >> Mobile Networks >>Access point Names /APN >> Go to APN Protocol Change it to IPV6 and APN Roaming Protocol to 'IPV4/Ipv6'.

Comment: this can help me fixed the problem. but in new android, some app doesn't exists such as **download manager**, **downloads**

Answer (score 1):

bro i am also using m5 just do one thing

when your download pause just go out and close play store from left button and your internet connection

wait for 30 seconds  and start internet connection  it will resume finally